# 'Delay until' finish time of 'Queue a new build' not working in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, timestamp, delay, azure-logic-apps

I'm triggering an Azure Logic App from an https webhook for a docker image in Azure Container Registry.

The workflow is roughly:

- `When a HTTP request is received`
- `Queue a new build`
- `Delay until`

  - `FinishTime` of `Queue a new build`

See: [Workflow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GXWR.png)

The `Delay until` action doesn't work in that the queueried `FinishTime` is `0001-01-01T00:00:00`.

It complains about the wrong format, so I manually added a `Z` after the `FinishTime` keyword.

Now the time stamp is in the right format, however, the timestamp `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z` obviously doesn't make sense and subsequent steps are executed without delay.

Anything that I am missing?

edit: `Queue a new build` queues an Azure pipeline build. I.e. the `FinishTime` property comes from the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been in touch with an Azure support engineer, who has confirmed that the `Delay until` action should work as I intended to use it, however, that the `FinishTime` property will not hold a value that I can use.

In the meantime, I have found a workaround, where I'm using some logic and quite a few additional steps. Inconvenient but at least it does what I want.

Here are the most important steps that are executed after the workflow gets triggered from a webhook (docker base image update in Azure Container Registry).

Essentially, I'm initializing the following variables and queing a new build:

- `buildStatusCompleted`: String value containing the target value `completed`
- `jarsBuildStatus`: String value containing the initial value `notStarted`
- `jarsBuildResult`: String value containing the default value `failed`

Then, I'm using an `Until` action to monitor when the `jarsBuildStatus`'s value is switching to `completed`.

In the `Until` action, I'm repeating the following steps until `jarsBuildStatus` changes its value to `buildStatusCompleted`:

1. `Delay` for 15 seconds
2. `HTTP` request to Azure DevOps build, authenticating with personal access token

[image: http request]

3. `Parse JSON` body of previous raw `HTTP` output for `status` and `result` keywords
4. Set `jarsBuildStatus = status`

After breaking out of the `Until` action (loop), the `jarsBuildResult` is set to the parsed `result`.

All these steps are part of a larger build orchestration workflow, where I'm repeating the given steps multiple times for several different Azure DevOps build pipelines.
The final action in the workflow is sending all the `status`, `result` and other relevant data as a build summary to Azure DevOps.

To me, this is only a workaround and I'll leave this question open to see if others have suggestions as well or in case the Azure support engineers can give more insight into the `Delay until` action.

Here's an image of the final workflow (at least, the part where I implemented the `Delay until` action): [image]

edit: Turns out, I can simplify the workflow because there's a dedicated Azure DevOps action in the Logic App called `Send an HTTP request to Azure DevOps`, which omits the need for manual authentication (Azure support engineer pointed this out).
The workflow now looks like this:

[image]

That is, I can query the build status directly and set the `jarsBuildStatus` as

```
@{body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_Azure_DevOps:_jar''s')['status']}
```

The code snippet above is automagically converted to a value for the `Set variable` action. Thus, no need to use an additional `Parse JSON` action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a timestamp in future, the timestamp `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z` you set to the "Delay until" action is not a future time. If you set a timestamp as `2020-04-02T07:30:00Z`, the "Delay until" action will take effect.

**Update:**

I don't think the "Delay until" can do what you expect, but maybe you can refer to the operations below. Just add a "Condition" action to judge if the `FinishTime` is greater than current time.

[image]

The expression in the "Condition" is:

```
sub(ticks(variables('FinishTime')), ticks(utcNow()))
```

In a word, if the `FinishTime` is greater than current time --> do the "Delay until" aciton. If the `FinishTime` is less than current time --> do anything else which you want.(**By the way you need to pay attention to the time zone of your timestamp, maybe you need to convert all of the time zone to UTC**)

Comment: I am using the dynamic content `FinishTime` because I don't exactly know how long the pipeline is gonna take, especially if the build task is waiting for an available build agent for some time. But the dynamic content `FinishTime` seems to have a default value that's (clearly) in the past. I would expect the `Delay until` action to recognize this (since it's built-in functionality) and keep querying until a sensible value is available.

Comment: Hi @AndreasHessenthaler I don't think the "Delay until" action can implement the requirements which you expect. But I provide some operations for your reference in "Update", please check.

Comment: Hi @hury-shen, thanks for the update and suggestion. Unfortunately, this also doesn't work because the body of the `Queue a new build` task doesn't get updated. It triggers the build and everything else is happening in the background. I found a workaround, however, where I'm sending http requests to the Azure DevOps API. I'll write a separate answer for this.